# Is there a way to `read` lazily?

Tags: haskell

I have probably just spend a day of computation time in vain :)

The problem is that I (naively) wrote about 3.5GB of (compressed) `[(Text, HashMap Text Int)]` data to a file and at that point my program crashed. Of course there is no final `]` at the end of the data and the sheer size of it makes editing it by hand impossible.

The data was formatted via `Prelude.show` and just at this point I realize that `Prelude.read` will need to the whole dataset into memory (impossible) before any data is returned.

Now ... is there a way to recover the data without resorting to write a parser manually?

**Update 1**

```
main = do
  s <- getContents
  let hs = read s :: [(String, M.Map String Integer)]
  print $ head hs
```

This I tried ... but it just keeps consuming more memory until it gets killed by the OS.

Comment: @n.m. even then `read` would try to read everything into memory before  returning a single element of the list.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, you mean Haskell `read` function, not reading from file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Daniels answer can be extended to parse the whole list at once using this function. Then you can directly access it as a list the way you want

```
lazyread :: Read a => [Char] -> [a]
lazyread xs = go (tail xs)
    where go xs = a : go (tail b)
        where (a,b) = head $ reads xs
```

Answer (score 9):

Sort of. You will still be writing a parser manually... but it is a very short and very easy-to-write parser, because almost all of it will ship out to `read`. The idea is this: `read` is strict, but `reads`, when working on a single element, is lazyish. So we just need to strip out the bits that `reads` isn't expecting when working on a single element. Here's an example to get you started:

```
> let s = "[3,4,5," ++ undefined
> reads (drop 1 s) :: [(Int, String)]
[(3,",4,5,*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

I included the `undefined` at the end as evidence that it is in fact not reading the entire `String` before producing the parsed `3` at the head of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Manually delete the opening '['.  After that you might be able to use `reads` (note the s) to incrementally access getContents.